# Monta link apenas quando houver dados

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma aplicação webforms. Nessa aplicação tenho essa linha no meu asp.net.

```
<strong><a href="/UpLoads/<%# Eval("DsPathDocumento")%>" class="linkUpload"><%# Eval("NmTipoDocumento")%></a></strong>
```

Bem, o que eu quero é que esse link só monte quando haver documento. Fiz assi e está dando erro de que só é possível dentro de um Databound.

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DsPathDocumento ").ToString())) { %>
                <<strong><a href="/UpLoads/<%# Eval("DsPathDocumento")%>" class="linkUpload"><%# Eval("NmTipoDocumento")%></a></strong>
                <% } %
```

>

Como eu resolvo isso?
Esse é o erro:

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

Comment: Qual é a propriedade no seu Dataset que diz que o registro tem ou não tem documentos?
A pasta é DsPathDocumento, mas deve haver uma propriedade tipo "TemDocumento" nesse seus Dataset, para você poder dizer se o link deve aparecer ou não.

Comment: O próprio campo DsPathDocumento é o campo que eu quero testar. Se ele trouxer alguma coisa é que existe documento, caso venha null ou vazio não tem documento. É por esse campo que eu quero criar o link.

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer somente que o link seja visualizado ou não, então use a Tag Style junto o a propriedade Display.

```
<strong>
    <a class="linkUpload" <%# Eval("SEQ_CHA") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("SEQ_CHA").ToString()) ? String.Concat("href='/UpLoads/", Eval("SEQ_CHA"), "'") : "href='#' style='cursor: default; color:#000000;'" %>>
        <%# Eval("NmTipoDocumento")%>
    </a>
</strong>
```

Comment: Alterei a resposta para ficar como especificado.

Comment: Sim, eles possuirão a tag de like HREF, mas não terão link para lugar algum. Se você quer suprimir a tag de HREF e deixar somente o texto escrito, então isto é outra coisa. O ternário está correto, eu testei.

Comment: Alterei novamente.

Comment: Cara, estamos quase lá e te agradeço mesmo. Só falta o seguinte e não sei como tirar. Continua o sublinhado e quando eu clico, ele volta para uma determinada página. Gostaria de ao clicar não acontecesse nada e como eu faço para retirar o sublinhado. Agora acho que o sublinhado tem a ver com a classe upload, vou testar aqui.

Comment: Não tem mais o link quando não conter nada, o sublinhado é da sua classe provavelmente.

Comment: Só que quando eu clico nele, me abre outra janela com isso: about:blank

Comment: Você está fazendo alguma coisa errada. Tenho certeza que o código dá certo, pois estou testando aqui. o "#" não redireciona para lugar algum, ele serve com âncora.

Comment: Eu removi o href='#' e agora me redireciona para uma página em branco apenas. Antes voltava para a página chamadora e depois que removi me redireciona para o about:blank e abre em outra  janela.

Comment: Removi o class="linkUpload" e agora o que não tem doc anexo não faz nada e o que tem doc, o link é criado, porem ambas as situações, cria o underline. Não consigo remover o underline.